# Designing iron core shell type transformer

Tags: transformer, design

I would like to design a iron core transformer of shell-type design. I have experience with electronics, but have never built a transformer before and would like to start simple, but not so simple I cannot learn.

How I can choose a core size, how is TPV important, and what are the effects fewer turns on the primary have on the transformer (assuming the secondary's windings are turned in proportion to keep the same voltage)?

The fewer the windings the lesser the magnetic field, will that affect saturation? Can I use a smaller core if I use fewer windings? How do I choose the core size?

I found a formula for core size saying:

Core area = 1.152 * square root of output voltage * output current

Is that accurate? I don't see how it is, he did not provide an explanation as to how it is accurate...

To summarize: I would very much appreciate some help in finding a core size, what exactly saturation is, the effects of windings in saturation or energy distribution, and how to choose a number of windings for the primary that is optimal for the core.

I have done a lot of research and have come here for some final clarifications. Of course you don't have to answer all my questions, I know I have many!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say 'iron core' transformer. I'll make the assumption that means mains frequency.

Start the design from the magnetic core. As it's mains frequency, we do not need to worry about core heating, which complicates the design in the case of high frequency ferrites. Therefore we can choose the flux excursion from saturation alone. Aim to run it to a large fraction of the saturation flux density, so to maybe to a B field of +/- 1.5 T, most 'transformer irons' should handle this.

The changing flux in the core generates a voltage around the windings, volts per turn = rate of change of flux, \$V=\frac{d\Phi}{dt}\$.

That's flux \$\Phi\$, not flux density \$B\$. Flux (Webers) = Flux density (Tesla) * core area (m<sup>2</sup>).

For a sinusoidal waveform (another assumption), the peak rate of change of flux is related to the peak flux via frequency, \$ \frac{d\Phi}{dt} _{peak} = 2\pi f  \Phi_{peak}\$. Draw a simple graph of one cycle of a sinewave, and compute its slope as it crosses zero, in terms of its frequency, if you want to see where this equation comes from. I can't remember it, so it's what I do each time.

That's your volts per turn related to your core area and operating frequency. Remember that's peak voltage, so the RMS voltage will be 0.7071 of that.

Most commercial cores are much the same aspect ratio, so the core area more or less dictates your other core parameters like winding window area, weight, magnetic length etc.

The power handling of a transformer varies depending on the duty cycle, and whether it's temperature rise or voltage sag that is your limit. The easiest way to size a core for normal continuous use is to look at an online catalogue of mains transformers of various power ratings, and plot their mass against rated power. Assume half the mass is copper and half iron, and that will give you a ballpark mass for your core.

With a core mass, go from core area and frequency to volts per turn. Then compute your number of turns for primary and secondary. Add a few percent onto the secondary turns to allow for voltage droop due to IR voltage losses in the windings.

Answer (score 0):

U<sub>RMS</sub>=4.44fNAB

where

- U<sub>RMS</sub> is your applied voltage in volt.
- f is your mains frequency in hertz.
- N is your number of primary turns.
- A is your core area in m^2.
- B is your peak flux density in tesla.

B is set by your core.

Assume worst case overvoltage to build in margin. Adjust your number of turns. You will find that by choosing thin wire and many turns, the core will remain happy but your wire will overheat and melt. This becomes a balancing act. One simplified approach is to set your current density to a fixed sane level and calculate how many turns you need for each given core size. If the wire does not fit, you need a larger core.

Comment: Is N the number of turns?

Comment: @ChesterGillon Indeed. Thanks for noticing. I've updated my answer.